# Is there an English translation for Excerpta de Legationibus, Constantine?

Tags: ancient-rome, primary-source

I'm looking into primary sources about the Huns by **Priscus of Panium**. [The Fragmentary Classicising Historians of the Later Roman Empire, R.C Blockley](https://ia803405.us.archive.org/6/items/the-fragmentary-classicising-historians-of-the-later-roman-empire-eunapius-olymp/FRAGMENTARY%20CLASSICISING%20HISTORIANS1.pdf) directed me to to Constantine's *Excerpta de Legationibus*. This [source](https://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/view/MS-TRINITY-O-00003-00023/1) provides complete images of handwritten document in Greek. Are there any English translations available? Thanks.

Comment: There is a Bibliography in the right column, among the titles is "Menander, The history of Menander the Guardsman : introductory essay, text, translation and historiographical notes, ed. R. C. Blockley (Liverpool: Cairns, 1985)." So Blockley did the translation himself, but only after publishing the book you read.